# Python: IndexError: list index out of range and Syntax Error

Tags: python, file, csv, syntax-error, index-error

I m writing a python script to compare 2 csv files: one contains 2 columns and the other contains 1 column. The aim of this script is to sort out all the matched lines. But each time i try to run the script i get an error in syntax or in index. Can you help me please to correct my script?

```
import csv
reader1 = csv.reader(open('interactors.csv', 'r'), delimiter=" ")
row1 = next(reader1)
reader2 = csv.reader(open('proteome_plas.csv', 'r'), delimiter=" ")
row2 = next(reader2)
if (row1[0] == row2[0]) or (row1[0] == row2[1]):
    print ("match")
else:
    print ("different")
```

Comment: Do the `csv` files have the headers on them? Presumably `reader2` is the one with two columns? Can you give an example first few lines from the two CSV files? Try printing out the rows before you index them to see which rows gave the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to print and you will see:

```
    import csv
    reader1 = csv.reader(open('interactors.csv', 'r'), delimiter=" ")
    row1 = next(reader1)
    print(row1)
    reader2 = csv.reader(open('proteome_plas.csv', 'r'), delimiter=" ")
    row2 = next(reader2)
    print(row2)
```

The output will be:

```
['col1', 'col2'] - row1
['col_11'] - row2
```

You trying to get access to row2[1] element wich does not exist

Try that:

```
    import csv
    reader1 = csv.reader(open('interactors.csv', 'r'), delimiter=" ")
    row1 = next(reader1)
    print(row1)
    reader2 = csv.reader(open('proteome_plas.csv', 'r'), delimiter=" ")
    row2 = next(reader2)
    print(row2)
    # Maybe in your case need to fill row2 to len(row1)
    if row1 == row2:
        print ("match")
    else:
        print ("different")
```

And if you want to get any equal element:
use

```
max_row = row1 if len(row1) > len(row2) else row2
min_row = row2 if len(row1) > len(row2) else row1

for elem in min_row:
    if elem in max_row:
        print('match')
        break
```